# Finding the $MLE$ of $\theta$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, estimators

Let $X_{1}$,$X_{2}$,......$X_{n}$ be a random sample of size $n$ from a distribution with pdf

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac1\theta,&2\theta\le x\le 3\theta\\0,&\text{elsewhere.}\end{cases}$$
where $ \theta > 0$. What is the $\text{MLE}$ of $\theta?$

I began by finding the likelihood function:

$$ L = {\frac{1}{\theta}}^{n}$$

For $L$ to be  maximum, $\theta$ has to be minimum.

So for this question is the MLE of $\theta$ at $$ \frac{\min(x_{1},x_{2},......x_{n})}{2}$$ or $$ \frac{\max(x_{1},x_{2},......x_{n})}{3}$$
or both?

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comments, $\theta$ lies between $(\frac{\max(x_{1},x_{2},......x_{n})}{3},\frac{\min(x_{1},x_{2},......x_{n})}{2})$

So thereby taking the minimum value of $\theta$ to maximize $L$ we arrive at

$$ \theta  = \frac{\max(x_{1},x_{2},......x_{n})}{3} \ as \ the \ MLE$$

Comment: I think it might be clearer if you explicitly add the support to the likelihood

Comment: The support? As in how I arrived at $L$?

Comment: The "support" that jld refers to is the region in which $L$ is non-zero. It's a technical term. jld is saying to write out $L$ in a similar manner in which you wrote out $f(x).$

Comment: You have to take into account that for the likelihood to be non zero all observed values should be in the interval $(2\theta,3\theta)$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thank you for clarifying but I do not know the exact support for $L$. How do I compute it?

Comment: You explicitly tell us the support for any data value is the interval $[2\theta, 3\theta].$  Given a set of data values, then, what are the possible values of $\theta$ that could give a nonzero likelihood?

Comment: @whuber Okay I think I am following on.  $\theta$ lies between ($\frac{max(x_{i})}{3},\frac{min(x_{i})}{2} )$ and therefore taking the smallest value of $\theta$ the $MLE$ is at $\frac{max(x_{i})}{3}$ ?

Comment: I think you have it.