# Maximum Likelihood Estimator of $\theta$ for U($-\theta$,$\theta$)

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, uniform-distribution

> Let $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$, $X_{3}$.......$X_{n}$ be a random sample from $U(-\theta,\theta)$ distribution

So the $Likelihood \ function$ is

$$ L = (\frac{1}{2\theta})^{n}$$

To maximize $L$ we need to find the minimum value for $\theta$

Now $x_{i}$ lies between  $(-\theta \leq x_{1},x_{2}.......,x_{n} \leq \theta) $

Therefore  to find the minimum value of $\theta$ we get

$$ x_{(n)} \leq \theta $$

and

$$ -x_{(1)} \leq \theta $$

So therefore is the **MLE** the $max(-x_{(1)}, x_{(n)})$

Comment: I think it is what you are saying

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Thanks. A part of me thought the **MLE** is the min$(-x_{(1)}, x_{(n)})$

Comment: How do you obtain this expression for $L$?  Why does it not depend on the sample?  Isn't your expression for $L$ ($1/\theta^2$) minimized by letting $\theta$ become arbitrarily large?  How, then, does that lead to your expression for the MLE?

Comment: @whuber My mistake. I made the changes. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Which mistake?  Changing $L$ to $1/(2\theta)$ hasn't fixed any of these problems.  Recently you asked a nearly identical question (at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545590/finding-the-mle-of-theta).  Follow the advice that was given to you there, especially concerning using an indicator function to represent the support explicitly in the likelihood function.

Comment: I had initially written $L = \frac{1}{\theta^2}$ and changed it to $\frac{1}{2\theta}$. Isn't this right?

Comment: Neither is a correct likelihood function.  Neither one is even a probability density.  You need to multiply $1/(2\theta)$ by a suitable indicator function to show the density is *zero* beyond a given range.  Then you need to *combine* these densities, based on a sample, into a likelihood for the sample.  It *must* explicitly depend on the sample values.

Comment: Please search the site. Answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/360725/119261.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you for the link. I went through it and it seems my answer is correct